# Reusing Runnable objects

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Is there any way that I can run a fixed maximum amount of threads in parallel and REUSE the Runnable object as soon as one of the threads finishes? So, given N sets of running parameters for Runnable obj and only M Runnable objects (M < N) is there a way to make sure that as soon as one of the threads using a Runnable object finishes, I start a new thread using the same Runnable obj (thus a maximum of M threads running at one time) ?

Comment: The solution to your problem lies within the high-level concurrency framework provided in the Java Executor and ExecutorService framework.   You would use this to create a thread pool (probably of fixed size).  Then you would use a producer-consumer pattern to enqueue your runnable tasks.

Comment: I've read about the ExecutorService already, my issue is as the title specifies REUSING the Runnable object as soon as one thread finishes.

Comment: Reusing a runnable sounds like bad design to me. A runnable should be dedicated to a single thread, and when that one terminates, it means the task inside the runnable should be complete anyway. Why would you want another thread to execute it again?

Comment: The idea that you want to re-use a `Runnable` in a new thread as soon as some older thread ends makes me wonder, why did the old thread end?  Creating and destroying threads is expensive.  If each `Runnable` represents a different _task_, why not design your thread to keep running, and perform task after task after task...?  That design idea is called _thread pool_, and the `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` and related classes have already implemented it for you.

Comment: Reusing a Runnable in a system where object allocation should be kept at minimum is not a bad design at all. I'm processing AI game-trees with a symmetric search algorithm. But yes I could design a thread to do task after task and distribute all the tasks to the fixed number of Runnables and then execute them. Cheers.

Comment: Why do you want to reuse Runnables? Please explain. If only to save time and space for allocating Runnable objects, then this would give no effect, because each time you create a Thread object, which is much more heavyweight than a Runnable. Not only a Thread occupies many more space, but also it has complex initialization to be embedded in O/S.

Comment: Well to deal with the thread allocation issue I use ExecutorService with thread pool. And because I'm trying to remove any work from the GC due to the results shown by the profiler I wanna reduce allocation as much as possible anywhere I can.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement Producer-Consumer pattern like:

```
    int n = 10;
    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
    final BlockingQueue<Object> tasks = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1024);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        Object task = tasks.take();
                        // process task
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    tasks.put(new Object());
```

Comment: As I have specified I need a way of reusing a fixed amount of Runnable obj, not defining a new one for each new task.

Comment: In practice it is what you need: we do not create runnable for each task but use fixed number of runnables.